# How to add a custom component in Ionic (3)?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a sign up page module, where I am attempting to include a custom component: "EaterSignUpModule" (soon to be a module with two custom components, for the different user roles)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SignupPage } from './signup';
// components
import { EaterSignupModule } from './components/eater-signup/eater_signup.module';
// services
import { SignUpService } from './services/signup.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SignupPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(SignupPage),
    EaterSignupModule
  ],
  exports: [
    SignupPage
  ],
  providers: [
    SignUpService
  ]
})
export class SignupPageModule { }
```

This is my custom component's module file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
// components
import { EaterSignUp } from './eater_signup';
// services
import { SignUpService } from '../../services/signup.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    EaterSignUp
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    EaterSignUp
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    EaterSignUp
  ],
  providers: [
    SignUpService
  ]
})
export class EaterSignupModule { }
```

And this is the components typescript file/class file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController, App, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
// interfaces
import { Credentials,
  EaterProfile,
  VendorProfile,
  VehicleDimensions
} from '../../../../interfaces/main.interfaces';
// services
import { SignUpService } from '../../services/signup.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'eater-signup',
  templateUrl: 'eater_signup.html',
})
export class EaterSignUp {

  constructor(
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public signUpService: SignUpService,
    public app: App
  ) {
    this.initialize();
   }

  public initialize(){

  }

}
```

Code for where I actually use the selector:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="viewState=='eaterSelected'">
  <eater-signup></eater-signup>
</ng-container>
```

My understanding of doing this sort of thing in ionic is limited (IonicPage and IonicPage Module)

**I am faced with the following error: "Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'eater-signup' is not a known element:
1. If 'eater-signup' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module....."**

In normal angular I usually just declare the component, and don't even need a module for it.

Would appreciate any help with this. Thanks

Comment: is the component used only in signup page?

Comment: can you post the code you use the eater-signup selector

Comment: `In normal angular I usually just declare the component, and don't even need a module for it.` - This is true only if you are utilizing the component inside the same module. Anywhere else you will have to export the components inside module to be utilized by other modules.

Comment: @SurajRao Yes it is

Comment: @Sajeetharan will do